# SSL causing Dalays in Odoo 16 POS

Tags: ssl, websocket, gevent

I am using Odoo16 POS which is connected to kitchen display screen for order preperation, using a custom built app.

Everything works fine, but when I configure SSL on my server, with Nginx, the point is reloading with every  new order added for a new customer. loading everytime for 4-6 seconds.

I am using 8 GB Ram with 2 CPU.

We are also using one teblet, for waiters to take orders from the table side, again, whenever new order is added to the system, the till will reloead for 4-5 seconds.

This problem only happens when using SSL and adding workers = 2 to the odoo config file, as instructed by the developer.
is there a way to avoid workers and still configure kitchen screen.

I tried increasing the server specs from
2 RAM and 1 CPU
to
8 RAM and 2 CPU
and it did not resolve.

If I completely remove ssl, the system works fine without reloading.
the problem is coming workers, websocket and gevent